# Form - checking for non empty field

Tags: javascript, html

It just refreshes the page when i don't fill in the values i want a text to  appear that says please input value and i taught that would happen but instead its just refreshes i don't know what to do please help Y-Y.

PS: this is my first time using this forum and im fairly new to do this but i wanna get more involved so any advice will be appreciated or if i am doing something wrong please do tell Thx :3.

```js
function required()
{
var empt = document.forms["form1"]["name"]["Email"]["country"].value;
if (empt == "")
{
alert("Please fill out all the boxes");
return false;
}
else 
{
alert('Code has accepted : you can try another');
return true; 
}
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Contact us!</title>
 <center><img id="banner" src="contact.png" alt="Banner Image"/></center>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css" type="text/css" />
</head>
<style>
/*Header is unique cause its a banner header which uses a image as a banner i found this on stock overflow comment section it has been edited to fit my needs*/
 head{ background: url("contact.png") repeat;}
#banner {
  position:center ;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  width: 40%;
  height: 300px;
  z-index: -1;
}

.footer {
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
    padding: 10px;
    text-align: center;






textarea {
    width: 100%;
    height: 140px;
    padding: 12px 20px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border: 2px solid #ccc;
    border-radius: 4px;
    background-color:#C99CDC;
    font-size: 16px;
    resize: none;
}
</style>
<body>


  <div class="topnav">
  <a href="Home.html">Home page</a>
  <a href="SEARCH.html">Search page.</a>
  <a href="Merchendise.html">Merchendise</a>
</div>
<br>
<form name="form1" action="#" onsubmit="required()">
  Name:
  <input type="text" name="name">
  
  
  Email:
  <input type="text" name="Email">
  
   Location
   <select id="country" name="country">
  <option value="Null"></option>
      <option value="australia">Australia</option>
      <option value="canada">Canada</option>
      <option value="usa">USA</option>
   <option value="indoasia">Indoasia</option>
   <option value="japan">japan</option>
   </select>
   <br>
   <br>
   <textarea rows="9" cols="125"></textarea>
   <br>
 <input type="submit" value="Submit">
 </form>
 </div>
<div class="footer">

<address>
</a>.<br> 
<br>
deakin.com<br><br><br>
</address>
<p>  ©
Deakin College.</p>
</div>

<script src="contact.js"></script>





</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It helps if you use correct capitalisation, phrasing and grammar in your question. Also, indenting your code helps with readability. The more effort you put in to asking the question, the better the responses will be. ;-) Also post code as a runnable snippet and keep it to an absolute minimum to display the issue. Irrelevant CSS, HTML, etc. should be removed.

Comment: You might just want to use the attribute `required`. That will prevent the page to send the data if all the required fields are not containing data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add the `required` attribute to the required from controls and the browser will prevent the from from being submitted unless the fields are filled in.

Here is one way to fix your code, but RobG's solution is better because you can add more fields without modifying your js.

Also, empt as a variable name is not very meaningful...

```js
function required()
{

var empty = document.forms["form1"]["name"].value && document.forms["form1"]["Email"].value && document.forms["form1"]["country"].value;

if ( ! empty )
{
alert("Please fill out all the boxes");
return false;
}
else 
{
alert('Code has accepted : you can try another');
return true; 
}
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<form name="form1" action="#" onsubmit="required(); return false;">
  Name:
  <input type="text" name="name">
  
  
  Email:
  <input type="text" name="Email">
  
   Location
   <select id="country" name="country">
  <option value=""></option>
      <option value="australia">Australia</option>
      <option value="canada">Canada</option>
      <option value="usa">USA</option>
   <option value="indoasia">Indoasia</option>
   <option value="japan">japan</option>
   </select>
   <br>
   <br>
   <textarea rows="9" cols="125"></textarea>
   <br>
 <input type="submit" value="Submit">
 </form>
```

Comment: Right you are. Updated.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I know this wasn't part of my question but i just realized that i need to check and make sure the user inputs a full-stop and a @ in the email part of the form can i include .                                        function validateEmail(email) 
{ var re = /\S+@\S+\.\S+/;
    return re.test(email);}.

Comment: Use type="email" in that input and the browser will validate it for you.

Comment: Wow such a fast reply thank you i will check it out.

Comment: it works thank  but if i would like to go about with it using java script how could i do it?. I am like a total novice and please do tell me if i am asking to much thx.

Comment: Take a look at https://www.w3resource.com/javascript/form/email-validation.php and you'll see that though there are ways to do this with javascript using a regex. There is some confusion about what is a valid email and what common emails look like so you'll see that this regex is quite a bit different from the one in the comment above.

Answer (score 2):

There are probably many duplicates but I can't find one right now.

You need to loop over the controls in the form and check their values,

```
var empt = document.forms["form1"]["name"]["Email"]["country"].value;
```

doesn't do what you think (concatenate all the values maybe?). To check all the values, you can turn the controls into an array, then use *every* to check that they all meet a particular condition, e.g.

```js
// Pass reference to form from listener
function required(form) {

  // Loop over controls in form, checking that they all meet a condition
  return Array.from(form.elements).every(function (control) {

    // Ingore submit button (may want to ignore others)
    if (control.type != 'submit') {

      // If value is empty, return false
      if (control.value == '') {
        return false;
      }
    }

    // Otherwise, return true
    return true;
  });
}
```

```html
<!-- Pass reference to form in call using 'this' -------^^^^ -->
<form name="form1" action="#" onsubmit="return required(this)">
  Name:<input type="text" name="name"><br>
  Email:<input type="text" name="Email"><br>
  Location: <select id="country" name="country">
    <option value="Null"></option>
    <option value="australia">Australia</option>
    <option value="canada">Canada</option>
    <option value="usa">USA</option>
    <option value="indoasia">Indoasia</option>
    <option value="japan">Japan</option>
  </select><br>
  <textarea rows="9" cols="125"></textarea><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Comment: select-option returns "Null" if no item is selected, I just checked.

Comment: @volvox—depends on the browser. Some will make the first option the default selected, some don't. It's recommended to always set one option as the default selected to remove doubt. Anyway, the OP's test is `empt == ""` and "null" is not "" so works per requirements. ;-)